# Mayavi colormap working for imshow but not working for image_plane_widget

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I have written some code using TraitsUI and Mayavi. I have two matricies:

1. NxN which is called imageArray2Dmesh - a column density of 'data'.
2. NxNxN which is called data.

When I do the 2D render using imshow I get the following:

```
self.scene.mlab.clf()   
self.scene.mlab.imshow(np.log10(self.imageArray2Dmesh),colormap=self.possible_colormap)
```

[image]

but when I do the cross-section version, I get the following:

```
            self.scene.mlab.clf()
            self.scene.mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(self.scene.mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(np.log10(self.data)),
            plane_orientation='x_axes'
            colormap=self.possible_colormap)
            self.scene.mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(self.scene.mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(np.log10(self.data)),
            plane_orientation='y_axes',
            colormap=self.possible_colormap)
            self.scene.mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(self.scene.mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(np.log10(self.data)),
            plane_orientation='z_axes',
            colormap=self.possible_colormap)
```

[image]

Is there any reason why this is happening? It should just look like 3 slices with the colormap shown in the 2D case! Is it because I am running the same scene in the same window?

Comment: Does this occur when you use a built in colormap like 'jet'?  I just tested nearly identical code using built-in colormaps and it works.  The next question is which version of mayavi are you using?

Comment: Thanks. It does the same with jet - correct with 2D, incorrect with 3D. I am using version 4.2.0 with Python 2.7.3 as part of EPD 7.3.2 using VTK version 5.3.0 and wxPython 2.8.10.1. I am using traits in conjunction with this. I have two buttons, each time I click one, it executes a definition for each button which are the two codes above. e.g. def _plot_viz_threeD_fired(self): self.scene.mlab. etc.

Comment: I'm either at the same versions or behind (however I'm on a linux system not using wxPy or EPD), so its unlikely its Mayavi unless they borked something in an update.  I made a little script for testing the color map on generic data, test that out.  https://gist.github.com/4544237  If that works then its something in your script, if it doesn't work then you should post something to the Enthought guys.

Comment: Yes that works as it is just the example from Enthought. Though I can't work out why mine isn't working. It has something to do with the buttons and not resetting the workspace perhaps? is there a command I should be using to reset the window each time a new button is pushed? Perhaps it is getting confused between scenes.

Comment: The fact that you can even get it to this point seems like its a problem with the mayavi pipeline. Are you redrawing the entire scene when the button is pressed?  If you draw the plane_widgits first does the coloring work?

Comment: All I am using is self.scene.mlab.clf() to clear the scene. How do I redraw it entirely? The plane_widgets is draw second as it is the outer part of the pipeline - I cant check that color.

Comment: It works with your example when I press the button, though when I use  np.log10(self.data) in the scalar_field part it goes bad.

Comment: I think I've worked it out. When it is doing the 3D slices, there are holes of value = 0 in the mesh and so when the contrast goes over the top for a slice, it goes from 0 to my other values and so there is a sharp contrast. The averaged image2DArray however, has no 0 values anywhere because it is averaged through the box, hence the contrast is fine.

Comment: I should have thought of that!  I've had that exact problem before, Mayavi has lots of quirks like that which can be frustrating.  Good on you for finding it.